# unable to record audio and getting message AudioFlinger: RecordThread: buffer overflow

Tags: android, audio-recording

In my app i have audio section where i have one **recordBtn** that will record audio and one **playRecordedAudioBtn** that will play just recorded audio and i have one more **playTrackBtn** that will play track(musical audio).

when i click **recordBtn** and **playTrackBtn**, recorded audio must have what i have recorded and track song both but it is not recorded what i want and gives message in logcat

**11-16 04:40:24.060: WARN/AudioFlinger(90): RecordThread: buffer overflow**

my recorded audio code is below:

```
new Thread(recordingThread).start(); // called thread from onCreate

private Runnable recordingThread = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                startRecording();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("error:", "" + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

    };

public void startRecording() throws IOException {

        String state = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState();

        if (!state.equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "SD Card is not mounted.  It is " + state + ".",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {

            String dirPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .getAbsolutePath();

            songTakePath = dirPath + "/SongWriters_Pad/"
                    + title_view.getText().toString() + "-Take-" + count
                    + ".wav";

            recorder = new MediaRecorder();
            recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);

            recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

            recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(16);
            recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);


            recorder.setOutputFile(songTakePath);

            try {
                recorder.prepare();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            recorder.start();
}}
```

please provide any guidance and some code snippet.
thanks..

Comment: have you try it in real device?

Comment: when i record my voice it is recorded clearly but i play track , the track is playing . problem is when i have to record my voice and playing track both.